# Recursive functions memory usage

Tags: python, memory, recursion

I have here a recursive function:

```
def pow(x, n):
    if n == 0:
       return 1
    else:
       return x * pow(x, n-1)
answer = pow(a, b)
```

And an iterative:

```
def pow(x, n): # n != 0
    answer = x
    while n > 1:
        answer *= x
        n -= 1
    return answer
answer = pow(a, b)
```

**I'd like to know which one of the them use more memory.** I think recursively uses more memory because it keeps 'variables' passed for each function call. If that's right, **what would be an formalism to explain this?** Is there a nice way to track this memory usage inside code?

---

I don't think It's a duplicate. The main question isn't about track the memory usage, but It's about the recursive memory usage.

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler?

Comment: I read about Guppy-PE, but I didn't get very well how to use it.

Comment: your iterative solution is incorrect.

Comment: thats true! fixing...

Comment: I'd like to know about the recursive thing too, I don't think its a duplicate.

Comment: iterative code is incorrect.  `pow(3,0) != 3` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No formalism is needed here.

Python stack frames are **huge**.

Your recursive code is using a lot more memory.

Typical CPython stack frame is over 50 elements plus local variables, taking x86_64 architecture as an example, that's almost 500 bytes.

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: inspect.stack()[1][0]
Out[2]: <frame at 0x7fed81c86850>

In [3]: inspect.stack()[1][0].__sizeof__()
Out[3]: 472
```

Good post about frame content: http://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/07/22/pythons-innards-interpreter-stacks/